# Trying to get JavaScript code completion to work in netbeans with jsdoc

Tags: javascript, netbeans-7, code-completion

In my app.js I have the following:

```
angular.module('app').controller('userList', 
  ['appSettings'
 ,function (/*@type {app.appSettings}*/appSettings) {  
   appSettings.<<== it shows a list here but nothing from autocomplete.js
```

In my autocomplete.js I have the following (generated by JavaScript printing out my services and their members):

```
var app={};
app.appSettings={};
app.appSettings.userFailMessages={};
app.appSettings.userFailMessages.invalidJson
  ="Invalid request, user sent is not valid json.";
```

NetBeans refuses to code complete appSettings for me and doesn't seem to know it's defined in autocomplete.js. Maybe I'm getting my js doc wrong but tried a mix of combination of @var, @type and @param without success.

It code completes when I type `app.appSettings.` and gives me a list from autocomplete.js but I would like to know how I can tell NetBeans that the passed argument to the function is app.appSettings.

Maybe I should have autocomplete contain constructor functions instead of object literals as @type suggests a certain type and not an instance.

This is NetBeans 7.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Was close to the answer, to have NetBeans use type you [have to define the type](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html). Then to indicate that the parameters passed to your angular module (or any function) are of a certain type I use the [@param](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html) [jsdoc](http://usejsdoc.org/)

The angular module:

```
angular.module('app').controller('userList'
 , ['$scope','appRules','appSettings'
 ,/**
* @param {app.appRules} appRules
* @param {app.appSettings} appSettings
* */
 function ($scope,appRules,appSettings,$timeout) {
   //<== here both appRules and appSettings give suggestions
   //  from autocomplete
```

autocomplete.js (not included in my html file but just there for code suggest)

```
/*@typedef {Object} app*/
var app={};
app.appRules={};
app.appRules.userIsInRole=function (user,role){};
app.appRules.general={};
app.appRules.general.isEmpty=function (val){};
app.appRules.general.isEmail=function (val){};
app.appSettings={};
app.appSettings.userFailMessages={};
app.appSettings.userFailMessages.invalidJson
 ="Invalid request, user sent is not valid json.";
app.appSettings.userFailMessages.noPrivilege
 ="You do not have the privileges needed to change this user.";
```

I ran the following code in the console on a page that contains my app to generate autocomplete.js:

```
var inj;
function allServices(mod, r) {
  if (!r) {
    r = {};
    inj = angular.element(document.querySelector('[data-ng-app]')).injector().get;
  }
  angular.forEach(angular.module(mod).requires, function(m) {
    allServices(m, r)
  });
  angular.forEach(angular.module(mod)._invokeQueue, function(a) {
    try {
      r[a[2][0]] = inj(a[2][0]);
    } catch (e) {
    }
  });
  return r;
};

var output=[];
function addOutput(names,prop){
  if(names.length===1){
    output.push('var ');
  }
  output.push(names.join('.'));
  if(typeof prop === 'object'){
    output.push('={};\n');
    for(thing in prop){
      //TODO: no arrays or route paths
      if(/[0-9\/\\]/.test(thing)){
        continue;
      }
      names.push(thing);
      addOutput(names,prop[thing]);
    }
  }else{
    output.push('=');
    output.push(
      (typeof prop === 'function')?
      prop.toString():
      JSON.stringify(prop)
    );
    output.push(';\n');
  }
  names.pop();
}

function createOutput(){
  allMyServices = allServices('app');
  addOutput(['app'],allMyServices);
  console.log(output.join(''));
}


createOutput();
```